# Understanding template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following code:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
using v_itt = typename std::vector<T>::iterator;

template <typename T>
void foo(v_itt<T>){ }

int main() {
    typename std::vector<long>::iterator i = std::vector<long>().begin();
    foo(i); //candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa007b07c04cefd8)

What's wrong with the code? I thought the `T` should have been deduced to `long`. Is there a way to fix that somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typename std::vector<T>::iterator
```

`iterator` (a dependent type) it is **not deducible** in your code since it is in a nested name specifier and the standard says

§14.8.2.5/4

> In certain contexts, however, the value does not participate in type deduction, but instead uses the values of template arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified. **If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.**

and §14.8.2.5/5

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> — The nested-name-specifier of a type that was specified using a qualified-id.

so this is a non-deduced context.

Possible workarounds:

1. Pass a vector reference instead of an iterator
2. Use tag dispatching and [compile time assertions](http://www.mersenneforum.org/showpost.php?s=1c4961ed7d9f81a9991f752f5a04b3b0&p=336909&postcount=4) to verify your iterator

Answer (score 4):

I'd like just to add a possible workaround 3 to Marco's answer:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
void real_foo( typename std::vector<T>::iterator){}

template <typename T>
void foo(T i){ real_foo<typename decltype(i)::value_type>(i); }

int main() {
    std::vector<long> v;
    foo(v.begin());
}
```

Comment: Good solution: even less verbose. Thanks Paolo.

Comment: @MarcoA. Well, it's not very elegant because it just relies on compile time failure providing no message to the user, but it's just another way of doing the same thing :)

Comment: @PaoloM That is also true. Good diagnostics are something to keep in mind as well.